# Why shouldn't we call setState() in componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle

I've been rereading React Docs and found this:"You should not call setState() in componentWillUnmount() because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again".

Can anyone explain please what this means and how it works? An example would also be cool.

Comment: When the component is unmounted it is being removed from the shadow and physical DOM.   The state you set here would never be used because, well, the component is being destroyed. 

I don't know for a fact; but I can only imagine that calling setState in `componentWillUnount` would cause issue with garbage collection and may produce hard to detect/debug errors in your application.